# what is a overclock kernel for android?

Tags: android, kernel

I have read about [overclocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overclocking) in wikipedia. I understand that we can change the clock rate in BIOS setup and it's hardware setup.
**So how does overclocking relate to the kernel, which is a kind of software?**

Comment: You're better ontopic over @ superuser I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- BIOS is kind of software too
- There is no BIOS on Android
- CPU frequency is dynamic nowadays, it has to be controlled during runtime and can't be set statically during boot
- read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling

Comment: thank you, that explains a lot.